# Has anyone seen a reputation jitter on Superuser lately?

Tags: support, reputation

For the last three days I find that my reputation is increased to nearly its daily cap sometime around mid-day. But, later this gets rolled back.

Looking at my rep history for the day when this spiked reputation is around,
I found that there was a series of upvotes over a short period of time,
typically one upvote per answer/question.

Today I also found that the spike after it was rolled back showed that I had also missed an upvote 3 hours back because I must have reached the daily-cap while this 'spike' was around.

So, my questions.

1. Is this something others have noticed with their Superuser accounts?

   - Does this make 'reputation' something of an approximation rather than a true-present value?
   - I am assuming here that reputation lost in this way will be added the next time such a recheck occurs

---

Aside: I also got the Meta-is-Murder maintenance page on the Meta site couple of times over the last two days -- leading me to assume Meta was down for maintenance. Apparently it was working fine.

---

**Update**: Thanks for those pointers `random`.
The two stackoverflow posts on [Voting Anomalies](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/more-voting-anomalies/) & [Fraud](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/) are good reference.

Some observations.

1. I checked that the rollback of reputation [has quite neatly carved out specific votes from a time-window](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16045/whats-the-point-of-voting-people-up-if-its-just-reversed/16050#16050)

   - some other votes which I got during that period are properly accounted
   - I presume that the anomaly detection identified a specific 'source' that pushed the votes and canceled their activity
   - Will check to see if the missed rep gets accounted correctly in the next round

Comment: Don't worry you got enough upvotes from me already!

Comment: Can't speak to the rep jitter, but the Meta-is-Murder was mostly from adding the acceptance rate % feature.

Answer (score 8):

The votes folding back might have been due to a [detected voting anomaly](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/more-voting-anomalies/) which would explain the blip and blup. Could have been sockpuppets were voting on your posts, or there may have been a user voting you up a ton and not realising it's not helping you out in the long run for such a burst like that.

You can read it in the new book out now in search with such salient chapters as, "[What is vote fraud?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3843/what-is-a-vote-fraud)" and "[What's the point of voting people up if it's just reversed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16045/whats-the-point-of-voting-people-up-if-its-just-reversed)"

Comment: +1 for a stupendous use of the word "salient."

Comment: @Eric: +1 for a salient use of the word "stupendous" :)

Answer (score 0):

Strange I haven't noticed anything other than the recent increase in "accepted answers"

I actually believe reputation is updated nearly instant, so the only thing I could think off are questions that are turned into community wiki.

Though it would unfair if the additional upvotes weren't counted when you got below the daily threshold again.

Comment: Well, about 7 hours back, my rep had crossed 7k. There was a bunch of upvotes (and reps), one per answer, about 3 hours old. These questions are not community wiki.

Comment: Then it is very strange